# Regex javascript - url structure

Tags: javascript, regex

I never was a regex expert, so I need some help with the following.

I have the following string: *`'<param1>(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>)))'`*.
This is a kind of url structure.
I want to extract: 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4' and to check if they are optional.
A param is optional if it is in parenthesis (param2, param3 and param4 in this case).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like it would be better done as a parser, not using a regex. You want to loop through each character, pushing a level onto a "stack" every time you hit a `(` and popping if you hit a `)`. You have an optional parameter if the stack is not empty.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is better to write a parser for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
var str = '<param1>(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>)))';
var optionnals = str.match(/\/<\w+>/g).map(function(s) { return s.replace(/\/<(\w+)>/, "$1"); });
```

But it might be difficult to have deep/recursive matching.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
//var str = '<param1>';
//var str = '<param1>(/<param2>)';
//var str = '<param1>(/<param2>(/<param3>))';
var str = '<param1>(/<param2>(/<param3>(/<param4>)))';

var result = str.match(/^<(.*?)>(?:\(\/<(.*?)>(?:\(\/<(.*?)>(?:\(\/<(.*?)>\))?\))?\))?/);

console.log(result[1]); //param1
console.log(result[2]); //param2
console.log(result[3]); //param3
console.log(result[4]); //param4
```

Answer (score -1):

May be without regex?

```
var str = 'param1/param2/param3/param4';
var res = str.split('/');
```